# Checking if application is suspended with resource monitor

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

I'm working on this home application (game anticheat) and I've ran into this problem. I think this is for "advanced" c# developers and I've decided to ask you.

So the problem is with suspending application. This anticheat is communicating with my game through sockets. When application is closed the user is kicked from the game, but when user suspends application with resource monitor my socket communication is not changing/closing and the player can run any hacks and/or unallowed softwares while it's on suspend.

I thought about creating a separate console application which will be monitoring main application process and if its < 0 it should terminate it. But there are some problems.

## 1 - I don't know it it's possible to run a console application from windows form application.

## 2 - I've tried using timers which would be checking for the main application status but console app closes immedieately after building it.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer t = new Timer(LauncherCheck, null, 0, 2000);
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void LauncherCheck(Object o)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process[] proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Anticheat");
                if (proc.Length < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Application is suspended / not running.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Application is running.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to prevent an administrator from suspending a process. You can launch another process from your program, I would not suggest a console process as that may be too visible.

Comment: I don't want to prevent it I just want to detect if the process is suspended. Is that possible ? And how can I make another process ? Any guides on that I'm pretty new.

Comment: Look at the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class, and `Process.Start`.